# Angular 14 fails to create new project

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

**Environment :**

- Windows 10
- nodejs 16.16.0
- npm 8.14.0
- angular 14.0.6

**Problem :**
When creating an angular new project

```
ng new myproject
```

I face a TLS error

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
```

I've tried

```
npm set strict-ssl false
npm cache clear --force
cd myproject
npm i
```

with no success. Any idea on how to solve that issue ?

**log extract :**

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
    3740 verbose stack FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-modules-local-by-default: 17396:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
    3740 verbose stack
    3740 verbose stack     at C:\Users\techn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\body.js:168:15
    3740 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    3740 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (C:\Users\techn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:99:25)
    3740 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (C:\Users\techn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:124:23)
    3740 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 203)
    3740 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Users\techn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1093:5)
    3740 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Users\techn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:218:7)
    3740 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
    3740 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\techn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:154:5)
    3740 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Users\techn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:145:5)
```

**notice :**
https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-modules-local-by-default can be retreived using my brower

Answer (score 0):

it's definitively an npm issue. To fix that I installed yarn package manager :

```
npm i --global yarn
```

setup Angular to use it

```
ng config --global cli.packageManager yarn
```

then configure it to avoid well know SSL issue (downgrading security level, but better than not being able to work !)

```
yarn config set strict-ssl false
```

***note : to switch back to npm :***

```
ng config --global cli.packageManager npm
```